# c# Deserialize custom class with nested classes

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize my xml into a custom object and I'm close, but the most nested element isn't populating, while all of the parents are working ok.

Here's the xml and classes for the deserialization process:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<dataMapping>
  <documentType attr1="blah" attr2="blah2" attr3="blah3">
    <indexFields>
      <indexField name1="field1A" name2="field1B" type="int" />
      <indexField name1="field2A" name2="field2B" type="int" />
      <indexField name1="field3A" name2="field3B" type="int" />
    </indexFields>
  </documentType>
  <documentType attr1="asdf" attr2="asdf2" attr3="asdf3">
    <indexFields>
      <indexField name1="field1A" name2="field1B" type="int" />
      <indexField name1="field2A" name2="field2B" type="int" />
      <indexField name1="field3A" name2="field3B" type="int" />
    </indexFields>
  </documentType>
</dataMapping>


[XmlRoot("dataMapping")]
public class dataMapping
{
    [XmlElement("documentType")]
    public List<DocumentType> DocumentTypes{ get; set; }

    public dataMapping() { }
}

[XmlRoot("documentType")]
public class DocumentType
{
    [XmlAttribute("attr1")]
    public string Area { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("attr2")]
    public string Cabinet { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("attr3")]
    public string SearchGroup { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("indexFields")]
    public List<IndexField> IndexFields{ get; set; }

    public DocumentType() { }
}

[XmlRoot("indexField")]
public class IndexField
{
    [XmlAttribute("name1")]
    public string Name1 { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name2")]
    public string Name2 { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string DataType { get; set; }

    public string ObjectValue { get; set; }

    public IndexField() { }
}
```

So, when creating my custom object via deserialization, everything is populating except the index fields, and their associated attributes. Where am I wrong in setting up that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figure out. I needed one more class (based on the way I have the xml structured) called "IndexFields", then that contains a list of "IndexField"....was just missing one level.

```
[XmlRoot("indexFields")]
public class IndexFields
{
    [XmlElement("indexField")]
    public List<IndexField> NestedIndexFields { get; set; }

    public IndexFields() { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add [XmlArrayItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx) it should help

```
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(IndexField))]
public List<IndexField> IndexFields{ get; set; }
```